# Set Local Notification for Specific Time

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsdatecomponents, localnotification

I am trying to schedule a local notification so it will occur at 9:00pm and repeat once a week. I have the following code and I keep receiving a error that says "Cannot assign value of type NSDateComponents to .fireDate. I understand .fireDate will only accept NSDate types but. I can not figure out a way to set the hour variable and minute variable for a NSDate type because I don't think it is possible to do this.

```
func Notification(){

    let dateComponents = NSDateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = 4
    dateComponents.month = 7
    dateComponents.year = 2016
    dateComponents.hour = 21
    dateComponents.minute = 00

    let Notification = UILocalNotification()

    Notification.alertAction = "Go Back To App"
    Notification.alertBody = "Did you complete your HH and QC?"
    Notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.WeekOfYear
    Notification.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

    Notification.fireDate = dateComponents
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(Notification)
}
```

Comment: Google calendar method dateFromComponents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it.

> Fully Tested on Swift 2.0

//Note I have taken date time from date picker

```
   func scheduleLocalNotification() {
        let localNotification = UILocalNotification()

        localNotification.fireDate = fixNotificationDate(datePicker.date)
        localNotification.alertBody = "Hey, you must go shopping, remember?"
        localNotification.alertAction = "View List" // Change depending on your action

        localNotification.category = "reminderCategory"

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
    }
```

//This function will help you in generating fire date.

```
func fixNotificationDate(dateToFix: NSDate) -> NSDate {
    let dateComponets: NSDateComponents = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components([NSCalendarUnit.Day, NSCalendarUnit.Month, NSCalendarUnit.Year, NSCalendarUnit.Hour, NSCalendarUnit.Minute], fromDate: dateToFix)

    dateComponets.second = 0

    let fixedDate: NSDate! = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(dateComponets)

    return fixedDate
}
```

Don't forget to request permission for push notification.

Link to my project i worked on 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2csGr9uKp1DR0ViZFZMMEZSdms

Answer (score 0):

You should get date from date components like this:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
calendar.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
calendar.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
let date = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)!
Notification.fireDate = date
```